# Multivariate Regression in Python

Tags: python, regression, multivariate-testing

I want to perform a multivariate linear regression in Python based on multiple arrays of dependent data and multiple independent ones.

I've seen a lot of MULTIPLE linear regressions, with multiple independent input and almost everyone is thinking that multiple=multivariate, but it's not. I can't see any true multivariate tutorial in the Internet. What I want is multiple output + multiple input.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn import linear_model
import tkinter as tk 
import statsmodels.api as sm

Stock_Market = {'Year': [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
                'Agriculture': [1, 0.8965517282485962, 0.4350132942199707, 0.5384615659713745, 1.1071428582072258, 0.1071428582072258, 0.1290322244167328, -0.07096776366233826, -0.37857140600681305, -0.439440980553627, -0.2020460031926632, -0.16339869424700737, 2.277777746319771], 
                'Demand_risk':[1,0.015701416,0.638652235,0.744531459,0.630988038,0.787568771,1.796302615,1.708789548,1.897916832,1.643077606,1.579785002,2.444568612,2.626896547],
                'International_risk':[1,1.609574468,1.225836431,1.30566937,1.771415837,1.737162303,2.156292933,2.365513975,2.502820771,2.660719511,2.468833192,2.624733983,2.577283326],
                'Production_risk': [1,0.76346912,1.421097464,1.423616355,1.434009229,1.307186577,1.378837063,1.3577073,1.744395371,1.744281735,1.559044776,1.570226289,1.116485043],
                'Technology_risk': [1,1.029845201,1.042711964,1.053634438,1.038367263,0.659816279,0.90179752,1.448686704,1.836091216,1.644680334,1.413661748,1.089683923,1.191047799]        
                }


df = DataFrame(Stock_Market,columns=['Year','Agriculture','Demand_risk','International_risk','Production_risk', 'Technology_risk']) 

X = df[['Demand_risk','International_risk','Production_risk', 'Technology_risk']] # here we have 2 input variables for multiple regression. If you just want to use one variable for simple linear regression, then use X = df['Interest_Rate'] for example.Alternatively, you may add additional variables within the brackets
Y = df['Year', 'Agriculture'] # output variable (what we are trying to predict)

# with sklearn
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y)

print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

# compute with statsmodels, by adding intercept manually
import statsmodels.api as sm
X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
result = sm.OLS(Y, X1).fit()
#print dir(result)
print (result.rsquared, result.rsquared_adj)
```

I want to change the output variable Y so that it can handle multiple arrays, not just a single one (now it throws an error).

Comment: The bug has nothing to do with the LinearRegression. It is here: Y = df['Year', 'Agriculture']. You have forgotten to put double brackets. The line should be Y = df[['Year', 'Agriculture']].

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me, though now I'm fighting with dimensions in statsmodels - I get an error: ,,shapes (13,2) and (13,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 13 (dim 0)". Do you know what could be causing it? (I inserted the part causing the error in the end of my code in the post)

Comment: My guess it that it does matrix multiplication somewhere. Try transposing one of the inputs to OLS. It might also be worth trying some of the other classes in the Linear Regression module https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html#module-statsmodels.regression.linear_model.

Comment: Okay, wait! How does this work with multivariate regression, in other words, multiple dependent variables? Because in statsmodels' OLS documentation (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS), it says that it only accepts "A 1-d endogenous response variable".

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an implementation like this:

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols._MultivariateOLS.html#statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols._MultivariateOLS

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at the moment.
Intended use appears to be:

```
import statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols

model = statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols._MultivariateOLS(y, X)

fit_model = model.fit()

results = statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols._MultivariateOLSResults(fit_model)

results.summary_frame()
```

But this results in a NotImplementedError.

```
    466     def summary(self):
--> 467         raise NotImplementedError
```

However, I did find I can do (what I *think* is) a MANOVA test through this, although the documentation seems to suggest it's a multivariate regression:

```
from statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols import _MultivariateOLS

model = _MultivariateOLS.from_formula('y1 + y2 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4',data)

results = model.fit() #method = 'svd'

mv_test = results.mv_test()

mv_results = statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols.MultivariateTestResults(mv_test.results
                                                                      , endog_names = y.columns
                                                                      , exog_names = X.columns
                                                                     )

mv_results.summary_frame
```

Info on [mv_test](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols._MultivariateOLSResults.mv_test.html#statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols._MultivariateOLSResults.mv_test)

It took me a while to find this due to the frustrating mix up most tutorials and texts make with "Multivariate" and "Multiple"... The only *actual* packages I've found that approach an answer to this is Sklearn's MLPRegressor and the SHAP package.

https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/model_agnostic/Multioutput%20Regression%20SHAP.html

https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-models-for-multi-output-regression/

But if you find another solution (that's not Neural Network based) PLEASE let me know. Thanks and goodluck

Comment: I have managed to write a user defined class that does multivariate regression in Python and also uses statsmodels to do some linear hypothesis testing. It is nothing fancy, just something along the lines of a tutorial, but can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real multivariate approach, but a hacky work-around

```
# analyze the data with statsmodels
X = df[['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4']]
y = df[['y1', 'y2']]

ms = {}
for col in y.columns:
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = sm.OLS(y[col], X).fit()
    ms[col] = model.summary()
#     mod = sm.OLS(y[col], X)
#     model = mod.fit()
#     ms[col] = model.summary()
# print(ms["y1"])
for k,v in ms.items():
    print(k, "\n", v, "\n")
```